# How to stimulate growth on one side of a young dwarf cherry tree

Tags: fruit-trees, cherries

Last year I purchased a dwarf cherry tree, which came as a maiden tree that I planted in a container and has now started to develop branches. However, it seems that all the branches are developing on one side (Viewed from above, they don't cover more than a 180 degree angle). I don't think this will be ideal for long-term growth; what can I do?

Comment: do you have pictures?